# Is there an offline inventory editor for Mac OS X?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I like building big buildings in Minecraft, but it's hard to get certain materials—like clay—on some of my maps.

So I'm looking for an inventory editor that works on Mac OS X. I currently use Inside Job, but when I make a new save, it doesn't save a world in the right slot even if the slot is empty.

I can use an online Minecraft inventory editor, but that's generally a slow process and online inventory editors usually don't have everything.

Comment: Ben - you should add what platform do you need the editor for. Most of them are for Windows, so if you are on Mac your choice will probably be more limited.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-15-01-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-may-10/), a in-game inventory editor for Minecraft, which is much easier to use than any other inventory-editing software for Minecraft that i've ever used. It is a mod, and requires editing the minecraft.jar file. There are quite a number of tutorials online on how to install, and should be easy enough.

[Inside Job](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/50392-inside-job-inventory-editor-for-mac/) has gone through quite a revamp, and should be working better now than in previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

A list if them can be found on the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors#Inventory_Editors). I recomend InvEdit because it has a search function and an inbuilt updater. Remember, you cannot edit the inventory of a map that is open.

Comment: When I tried InvEdit it didnt work (i have a mac)

Comment: @ben I wouldn't know, I don't have a mac. Check the forum link.

Answer (score 1):

I run Minecraft on Mac OS X, and the inventory editor I use is [InvGrid](http://starbytesoftware.com/projects/invgrid/). It's simple, works with 1.3, and is kept updated.

[image: InvGrid Screenshot]

Other features:

- World variable editing (e.g. time of day)
- LUA scripting support
- Ability to define and modify custom items based on ID (i.e. if you're using mods that add new items)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://nathancmatthews.com/mcinvedit/

this is from http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=199900

Also maybe this would be helpful http://wn.com/Minecraft_inventory_editor_for_Mac